# AWS CLI issues with connecting from local mac

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, was

I am trying to run AWS command from my local MAC, but the connection keeps timing out and traceroute is unable to get to my s3.us-east.amazonaws.com.

I have run aws configure, on both my local mac and my ec2.  It works on ec2 (not surprising), but not on my local MAC.

I have a single user who has sysadmin access.

As I said, AWS works on my ec2 instance and the following command yields the following.

Is there something else I need to do to get the AWS CLI to connect from my MAC?

```
    [root@ip-172-31-26-40 ec2-user]# aws s3 ls
2019-11-19 19:55:14 wildrydes.denis.putnam
[root@ip-172-31-26-40 ec2-user]# aws s3api list-buckets
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "denisputnam",
        "ID": "22873dab63c6750106aa2bf9f5584754d9b5449067a07c5ab57841967022f3fc"
    },
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "CreationDate": "2019-11-19T19:55:14.000Z",
            "Name": "wildrydes.denis.putnam"
        }
    ]
}
[root@ip-172-31-26-40 ec2-user]#
```

Debug output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
  File "site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 244, in _send
  File "site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 287, in send
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://iam.us-east.amazonaws.com/"
2019-12-04 17:20:51,304 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.iam.ListUsers: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7ff818983250>
2019-12-04 17:20:51,304 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - retry needed, retryable exception caught: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://iam.us-east.amazonaws.com/"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
  File "site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
  File "site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Do you mean `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`? Can you reach other internet locations, like Google? Are other AWS services reachable, like EC2 (`aws ec2 describe-instances`) or STS (`aws sts get-caller-identity`)? Are you using custom endpoints? Are you routing through a proxy that restricts access?

Comment: I can ssh into the ec2 instance.

Comment: And what about other AWS service endpoints? Do the other awscli examples I gave you work?

Comment: No, the other calls don't work.

Comment: I added some debug output and made sure I am running aws2.

Comment: Your debug output also shows `us-east`. Per my first comment, where is this coming from? It's not a valid region.

Comment: Ah-ha!  That was the problem!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might have been answered here:

[AWS S3 CLI - Could not connect to the endpoint URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409683/aws-s3-cli-could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url)

Essentially, perhaps your config file contains "us-east" instead of "us-east-1"

(The IAM timeout is trying to hit iam.us-east....But I dont think us-east without the 1 is an official region.)

Comment: Thank you, Daniel and jarmod!