# Cannot run AWS CLI from windows command prompt

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-cli

I am trying to run basic aws cli commands from my terminal( I am using windows command prompt).

```
aws iam list-users
```

result:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://iam.amazonaws.com/"
```

```
aws s3 ls
```

result:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

The aws config file is as below:

```
$ cat config
[default]
region = eu-central-1
output = json
```

The aws credentials file is as below:

```
$ cat credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKI***************N
aws_secret_access_key = Uu********************************se
```

My system is sitting behind a company proxy. What should i do to get aws cli working?

Comment: Does this solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411174

Comment: @Ersoy - For now I am able to run the commands with --no-verify-ssl. But is there somewhere i can get the aws certificates from and how do i install the certificates?

Comment: You may request and import one in aws console `Certificate Manager` - you need to add it to your user.