# AWS CLI Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When trying to do any AWS command, such as `aws s3 ls`, I get the error:

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.local.amazonaws.com/"

I have tried creating new access keys and rerunning `aws configure` with the following:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ****key****
aws_secret_access_key = ****secretkey****
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

I'm not sure where `local.amazonaws.com` is coming from, as it appears when calling other services too (like `"https://lambda.local.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions"`). Where is this endpoint URL coming from?

Comment: check your proxy ad firewall settings also is it just with s3 command or other cli commands too?

Comment: try running aw socnfigure again with a different region and see if error persist? and also which os you are using ? try this troubleshoot https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857589/13126651

Comment: macOS Big Sur 11.4, and it happens with other cli commands. Changing the region has the same result.

Comment: `aws s3 ls --region=us-west-2` what about this ?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra That works-- the buckets are listed if I have the `--region` flag

Comment: Probably your aws configuratio is worng try reconfiguring it, and try the troubleshoot i mentioned, in previous comments, make sure you have administrator policy access